# To translate $ S \lor (G \land (\neg S \lor \neg G)) $ to English sentences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

To translate  $ S  \lor (G \land (\neg S \lor \neg G))  $

S = Steve is happy

G = George is happy

$\neg S \lor \neg G$ means Steve is not happy or George is not happy

$ (G \land (\neg S \lor \neg G)$ means George is happy and ( Steve is not happy or George is not happy ).

So final becomes Steve is happy or ( George is happy and ( Steve is not happy or George is not happy ) )

Now i try to simplify it by making truth taking ans making cases for which this statement comes out to be true but it becomes too complicated and i was not able to reach to a conclusion. How do i simplify this ?

PS - Truth table values for which statement is true are

1. S = 0 G = 1
2. S=1 G =0

Comment: The statement is always true when $S=1$, no matter the value of $G$.

Comment: Yes but how will this help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the truth table correctly, you will get a $1$ unless $S=0$ and $G=0$.  That means your statement is equivalent to $S\lor G$.

Alternatively, note that
\begin{align}
S \lor (G\land (\neg S \lor \neg G))
&\equiv S \lor ((G\land \neg S) \lor (G \land \neg G))\\
&\equiv S \lor ((G\land \neg S) \lor 0)\\
&\equiv S \lor (G\land \neg S)\\
&\equiv (S \lor G)\land (S\lor\neg S)\\
&\equiv (S \lor G)\land 1\\
&\equiv S \lor G
\end{align}

Comment: i dont quite follow your first line

Comment: The sentence that begins "If you construct" or the first $\equiv$?

Comment: " If you construct the truth table correctly, you will get a $1$ unless $S=0$ and $G=0$.  That means your statement is equivalent to $S\lor G$.
"

Comment: Can you please show the truth table you made?

Comment: I just take cases where result is 1. But you have taken case where result is 0.

Comment: The truth table should contain four cases to cover all possibilities for $S$ and $G$.

Comment: but how to make formula out of truth table

Comment: Please show the truth table.